# Css @-viewport browser suppoer

Tags: css, viewport

I'm trying to find some definitive information on @-viewport CSS support.

Could somebody please advise how widely this is supported? I'm aware of IE and Opera - but what about Webkit on iOS and Android?

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently that's all there is for now.](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/atrules/@viewport#Compatibility)

For those who can't tell (at least one person), this is called a link to confirmation of what the original question is stating and what the other poster is also stating.

Answer (score 0):

Not that widely supported yet. IE10 (some features) and IE10 Mobile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh708740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and Opera Mini, version 11+ http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/